# Kinect Camera not recognized by Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, ros, kinect, xbox

So I have a Kinect 360 plugged via USB into a Raspberry Pi, with Ubiquity Robotics as the OS which comes with ROS, and have the freenect drivers installed per the guide here: https://openkinect.org/wiki/Getting_Started#Ubuntu.2FDebian

However lsusb only shows the NUI Motor on the Kinect, and nothing for the cameras

I tried reinstalling freenect, or checking if the user has the right privileges, but nothing changed the fact